# Surfaces on which not every pair of points is connected by a geodesic

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, geodesic

Let $S$ be a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
I believe that, if $S$ is smooth, bounded, and closed, then,
for every pair of points $x,y \in S$, there is at least one geodesic $\gamma$
connecting $x$ to $y$.
This is because there is certainly a path between $x$ and $y$, and then one
could shorten it until it is locally shortest and is then a geodesic.

> **Q1**. Is this correct?

If so:

> **Q2**. What are examples of
>   surfaces $S$—perhaps not smooth, not bounded, and/or not closed— for which
>   not every pair of points is connected by a geodesic?

Comment: Any smooth compact (that is, bounded and closed) surface is geodesically complete. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf%E2%80%93Rinow_theorem With respect to Q2, consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ and delete a half-line. Can you join any pair of points by a geodesic?

Comment: It's even enough to delete a single point!

Comment: @mfl and @ KevinCarlson: Thanks! But I wonder if there are examples without such deletions. Maybe orbifolds?

Comment: @WillJagy: I meant connected surfaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any smooth surface in $\mathbb R^3$ that is a closed subset of $\mathbb R^3$ is complete as a metric space. Thus, if it is also connected, the Hopf-Rinow theorem guarantees that it is geodesically complete, which in turn implies that any two points can be connected by a minimizing geodesic.

Therefore, the only ways that geodesic completeness can fail are

1. if the surface is not connected, as in @Will's example, or
2. if the surface is not closed, as in the case of a surface with a point removed.

This means that for connected surfaces, in a certain sense the *only* way for geodesic completeness to fail is if one or more points are "missing."  More precisely, if $S$ is connected but not geodesically complete, then it's not closed, which implies that there's a sequence of points $p_n\in S$ that converges to a point $q\in \mathbb R^3\smallsetminus S$. You can think of $q$ as a point that "should be" in $S$ but isn't. (But this doesn't imply that there was originally a smooth surface from which $q$ was removed -- for example, $S$ could be the cone $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ with the origin removed.)

Comment: I appreciate this clear answer, Jack! You have clarified exactly the issue that was confusing me. This captures it: "a point that 'should be' in $S$ but isn't."